# How to save images and variables to a file with pickle?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to save user configuration in pygame. 
When the user exits the game, it should save some info like themes (spooky, friendly, etc...) and the score using the pickle module. And when it is opened back again, the previously saved content would load in the game.

Let's say for example we have this bunch of code.

```
background = pygame.image.load('image full path')
score = 530

# Upon quitting
with open('GameSave', 'wb') as file:
   pickle.dump([bakcground, score], file)

# Upon opening
with open('GameSave', 'rb') as file:
    background = pickle.load(file)
    score = pickle.load(file)
```

But eventually, I get this when dumping:
`TypeError: can't pickle pygame.Surface objects`

So I think I'll have to use the `pygame.image.tostring`

The problem is how to convert it back to an image after I've loaded it.
And how to make sure that we're loading only the background for the `background` variable, and only the score for the `score` variable.

Comment: Why would you want to store the image, instead of just the path? Duplicating all game resources in a save game is a huge waste, and prevents updating content.

Comment: Well, I didn't know there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a reasonable need to duplicate the background image into the save-file, it should be fairly easy to pickle the "string" of the image, along with its size:

```
image_string = pygame.image.tostring( background, 'RGB' )
image_size   = ( background.width, background.height )
# TODO - pickle
```

And then when un-pickled again, convert it back into an image:

```
# TODO - un-pickle
image = pygame.image.fromstring( image_string, image_size, 'RGB' )
```